# Math mode in small environment

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize

i defined a new environment with the environ package, like:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{something}{
    \small
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[] \BODY
        \end{itemize}
}
```

My problem is now that i can't use math mode in this environment as the compiler is complaining that i can't use math mode and small at the same time:

```
! Font U/bbold/m/n/10.95=bbold11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.
```

I tried to solve it by loading some more packages but i still have the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is an error in code that you have not shown (or in your installation) latex is supposed to know what fonts are available and warn and substitute an available font, you are not supposed to get a low level font not found error. Please show a small but complete example that produces this error.

Comment: I don't have a bbold11 font in an up to date texlive2020 (I do have 5,6,7,8,9,10,12,17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTeX declaration for the bbold fonts in a file typically installed as

```
texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbold/Ubbold.fd
```

is

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> gen * bbold
      <10> <10.95> bbold10
      <12> <14.4> bbold12
      <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> bbold17
   }{}
```

Which tells LaTeX that at 10.95pt it should use a scaled version of the `bbold10` font.

Your error shows that LaTex tried to access a non existent `bbold11` font which means that some code you have not shown has bypassed this declaration and accessed the font directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I couldn't give an small example as i copied the part above from a class i write. The problem was that some others included `\RequirePackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}` which caused the trouble.

Comment: @Timres mathbbol.sty only access the fonts via standard latex interfaces so will not typically generate that error. You must have some code that is over-writing the `\DeclareFontShape` above and specifying an incorrect `bbold11` font. If you can track that down to a public package that is doing the wrong thing, we can get it fixed.

Comment: This is strange because without the above package everything works. I'll see if it happens again.